# How do you make StackWalk64() work successfully on x64?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, 64-bit, callstack

I have a C++ tool that walks the call stack at one point.  In the code, it first gets a copy of the live CPU registers (via RtlCaptureContext()), then uses a few "`#ifdef ...`" blocks to save the CPU-specific register names into `stackframe.AddrPC.Offset`, ...`AddrStack`..., and ...`AddrFrame`...; also, for each of the 3 `Addr`... members above, it sets `stackframe.Addr`...`.Mode = AddrModeFlat`. (This was borrowed from some example code I came across a while back.)

With an x86 binary, this works great.  With an x64 binary, though, StackWalk64() passes back bogus addresses.  *(The first time the API is called, the only blatantly bogus address value appears in `AddrReturn` ( == `0xFFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFE` -- aka StackWalk64()'s 3rd arg, the pseudo-handle returned by GetCurrentThread()).  If the API is called a second time, however, all `Addr`... variables receive bogus addresses.)*  This happens regardless of how `AddrFrame` is set:

- using either of the recommended x64 "base/frame pointer" CPU registers: `rbp` (= `0xf`), or `rdi` (= `0x0`)
- using `rsp` *(didn't expect it to work, but tried it anyway)*
- setting `AddrPC` and `AddrStack` normally, but leaving `AddrFrame` zeroed out *(seen in other example code)*
- zeroing out all `Addr`... values, to let StackWalk64() fill them in from the passed-in CPU-register context *(seen in other example code)*

FWIW, the physical stack buffer's contents are also different on x64 vs. x86 (after accounting for different pointer widths & stack buffer locations, of course).  Regardless of the reason, StackWalk64() should still be able to walk the call stack correctly -- heck, the debugger is still able to walk the call stack, and it appears to use StackWalk64() itself behind the scenes.  The oddity there is that the (correct) call stack reported by the debugger contains base-address & return-address pointer values whose constituent bytes don't actually exist in the stack buffer (below or above the current stack pointer).

*(FWIW #2: Given the stack-buffer strangeness above, I did try disabling ASLR (`/dynamicbase:no`) to see if it made a difference, but the binary still exhibited the same behavior.)*

So.  Any ideas why this would work fine on x86, but have problems on x64?  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: FWIW, the x64 ABI does not use a frame pointer register by default like x86 does, so you cannot unwind the stack based purely on register state + stack contents. The ABI does mandate unwind tables though, which are stored as part of the executable. The debugger is likely loading and using those.

Answer (score 2):

Given that fs.sf is a STACKFRAME64 structure, you need to initialize it like this before passing it to StackWalk64: (c is a CONTEXT structure)

```
  DWORD machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
  RtlCaptureContext (&c);
  fs.sf.AddrPC.Offset = c.Rip;
  fs.sf.AddrFrame.Offset = c.Rsp;
  fs.sf.AddrStack.Offset = c.Rsp;
  fs.sf.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  fs.sf.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  fs.sf.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
```

This code is taken from ACE (Adaptive Communications Environment), adapted from the StackWalker project on CodeProject.

Comment: Yup, I tried stackframe.AddrFrame.Offset = context.Rsp, but it didn't help. (See 2nd bullet point above.) Which _is_ a little odd, since the ASM code itself uses rsp as a base pointer w.r.t. function-local variables -- i.e., "mov  dword ptr [rsp+54h],eax" when saving StackWalk64()'s return value.

Comment: I've seen this code work so I know it's good.  Can you post more of your code -- for example, your call to StackWalk64() or a complete example?

Comment: The code's essentially the same as other code that does work.  At this point, I think it came from compiler options (cl.exe flags) -- I saw two build environments, both using the same compiler version (but diff. flags), produce binaries whose runtime [call] stack buffers looked extremely different.

Comment: Callstacks produced by StackWalk will often look very different based on many external factors: which dbghelp is available, the type of symbols/debugging information, etc.

Comment: Did not work for me either. Invalid addressing scheme ? (Vs2010, Windows 8)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I've switched to using `CaptureStackBackTrace()`, and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

`SymInitialize(process, nullptr, TRUE)` must be called (once) before `StackWalk64()`.