# Function Call Stack in C++

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, callstack

I have tried the following links, from StackOverflow and other sites,[I tried, but it didn't helped me, so i can't avoid duplicating]

[StackWalk64 on Windows - Get symbol name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705650/stackwalk64-on-windows-get-symbol-name)

[How do you make StackWalk64() work successfully on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136752/how-do-you-make-stackwalk64-work-successfully-on-x64)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx

http://jpassing.com/2008/03/12/walking-the-stack-of-the-current-thread/

[How to Log Stack Frames with Windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590160/how-to-log-stack-frames-with-windows-x64)
...

But none of the Code worked for me.I'm new to Windows C++ environment and i can't get any of the above code to work.

I'm looking for a call stack format like,
FUNCTION_NAME_DEPTH_1 : _LINE_NUM__
FUNCTION_NAME_DEPTH_1 : _LINE_NUM__
FUNCTION_NAME_DEPTH_1 : _LINE_NUM__ ...

Just function name and line numbers.

My Environment:
Visual Studio 2010
SDK : v7.1
Windows 7 Pro SP1

It would be a lot simple if anyone post a header file,[there seems to be few available,but not working] which we can include in our cpp file and print the call stack with a call like 'PrintFunctionCallStack();' . BTW in Linux/Mac, it was a whole lot easier,i was able to get the call stack from backtrace and it was so simple that i did it myself in few mins. In Windows i've have been trying past two days, but no surprise at all.

Linux/Mac Stack Trace Code, i haven't yet demangled the symbol names.

```
#ifndef _STACKTRACE_H_
#define _STACKTRACE_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>

static inline void PrintStackTrace()
{
        cout<<"##############################################\n";
        unsigned int maxStackCount = 63;
        void* addressList[maxStackCount+1];
        int addrLen = backtrace(addressList, sizeof(addressList) / sizeof(void*));
        if (addrLen == 0) {
            cout<<"Empty Stack, Probably Corrupted it seems ###\n";
            return;
        }
        char** symbolList = backtrace_symbols(addressList, addrLen);
        for (int i = 1; i < addrLen; i++) // Skipped First, 'i' begins with '1'
        {
                cout<<"###: "<<symbolList[i]<<":###\n";
        }
        free(symbolList);
        cout<<"##############################################\n";
}
#endif
```

Comment: Yet another link (to code that I believe works): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6207030/179910

Comment: Sorry, missed to include that link, i have checked that dude, but i would prefer something simpler.I have compiled it successfully and ran it, but no output at all. Just a simple function call like i posted above for Linux would be great.[No Separate Threads dude please].

Comment: Code for Linux will be *completely* different from code for Windows. The extra thread in the code I posted is only for test purposes (i.e., demonstrating dumping the thread's stack -- it's not part of the stack walking code at all).

Comment: Jerry, i know i'm asking a little too much, but can you please post it as a header file to include and the function to call which outputs the Call Stack. It's difficult for me to understand your code[My Mistake], i'm stuck, so any help's welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment is Visual Studio, you can insert a Tracepoint and input

```
$CALLSTACK
```

in its edit box, after checking Print a message.

To do it, right-click on the line you want and select Breakpoint > Insert Breakpoint (or alternatively, insert a breakpoint clicking on the left of the editor line you want, then select When Hit).

Then you will see a detailed report in the Output window, having file name, line number and function name. It served me to successfully discovered some memory leaks.